# Stroustrup and overflowing size_type in a loop

Tags: c++, iterator, size-type

I am reading *"Programming Principles and Practices using C++"* by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I would need a clarification about a surprising bit that I found in section 25.5.3. The author claims that if we want to iterate over an `std::vector`, then using a loop variable like

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
```

is less safe than using the iterators for the `vector` class:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); ++p)
```

because, being of an unsigned type, `i` could overflow. He states that the loop using iterators has no such limitation. I am a bit confused, since I learned that `size_type` is guaranteed to be big enough to represent the biggest possible vector, so a variable of type `size_type` will never overflow in a loop like that.

**EDIT**

To be more specific, he presents an example using a loop variable of type `int` before the other two, then at the end he states:

"The `size_type` is guaranteed to be unsigned, so the first (unsigned integer) form has one more bit to play than the `int` version above. That can be significant, but it still gives only a single bit of range (doubling the number of iterations that can be done). The loop using iterators has no such limitation."

Doesn't `vector<T>::size()` return a `vector<T>::size_type`? I don't see any limitation.

Comment: Are you sure you're representing the text accurately?

Comment: Unsigned integers don't overflow; I would expect Bjarne to know that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you probably mean that they overflow silently...

Comment: `std::size_t` is guaranteed to be big enough to represent the size of the largest possible object. `std::vector::size_type` is not guaranteed to be the same as `std::size_t`. It could be smaller.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Isn't it called wrapping?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't think so.  It never gets a change to overflow since it is mod 2^n to make it valid.  The standard says *Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.48*  and 48 is *This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the
resulting unsigned integer type.*

Comment: There's no need for a nonsensical discussion about whether unsigned types overflow. They DO overflow as ordinals. They DON'T overflow as modulo arithmetic value. It is a matter of choosing a conceptual interpretatuion.

Comment: Bjarne's books are surprisingly full of oddities like this.

Comment: @Lightness - Except that it is misquoted. Bjarne says that `for (int i = 0; ...` could overflow. And then recommends using either `size_type` or `iterator`. Then just mentions that *generally* using an unsigned type doesn't buy you much, as it is just one bit more.

Comment: @BoPersson: Thank you, that was my suspicion.

Comment: @KerrekSB: cool, we have infinite storage now !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: No, you still need to learn the rules of C++. Unsigned integers obey the laws of modular arithmetic. Let me explain your confusion by analogy: In your mindset, a clock either overflows, or a day is infinitely long. Neither is the case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I added the exact quote. Still, he implies that the version with `size_type` has a limitation with respect to the version with the iterator.

Comment: Yeah that's still a weird thing to say IMO. FWIW iterators are definitely preferable, but not because of this.

Comment: @KerrekSB: thank you for the lesson. The question is obviously in the usual sense of overflow, the one that Stroustrup used in the quote.

Comment: @Valerio - It's not the best example. *In general* using an unsigned integer isn't much better than a signed, because it is just slightly larger. I think Bjarne talks about this is several other places in the book. However, specifically the `size_type` of a container is always large enough to hold the maximum size - either because it is very large or because the size of the container will have to be limited by the available range. By definition `size()` will have to be able to always return the size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, yes, the paragraph you quoted does seem to indirecly imply or hint that `size_type` can be problematic. But I don't think it was the author's intent.

Note that the previous paragraph says (re: Second Edition)

> So, technically, most of the loops in this book have been sloppy [...]. To avoid this problem we can use the `size_type` provided by `vector`, iterators, or a range-`for`-statement:

In this paragraph `size_type` is presented a *solution* for potentially problematic `int` loops used in the previous sections of the book. It is mentioned as a safe alternative *together* with iterator or range-for version of the loop.

---

The potential overflow (or insufficient range) problem does exist when someone tries to use `std::size_t` to count or index elements of a non-array-based container, like `std::list`, `std::deque`, `std::map` etc,, instead of using container's own `size_type`. But it is a slightly different story, even if it is related.

Comment: Since `std::size_t` is large enough to represent every address on the system, how can you run out of range with any container? Maybe with weird allocators that obtain memory from subspace, I guess ^_^

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: `uintptr_t` is large enough to represent every address in the implementation's storage. `size_t` in general case is not. If your `size_t` is as wide as your `uintptr_t` - it is just a specific property of your specific implementation.

Comment: Hmm, I've always thought of them being necessarily equivalent, but I suppose you're right that the maximum size of an object may not necessarily be the same as the highest memory address.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: On flat-memory platforms they are usually the same. But on segmented-memory platforms `size_t` is typically smaller that "the whole memory" (smaller than pointer types), unless the user explicitly requests the compiler to implement memory model that "emulates" flat memory. Granted, not many segmented-memory platforms left around. But I heard segmented-memory IBM mainframes are still in use.

Comment: Yep fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

`vector::size` returns `vector::size_type`, so therefore `vector::size_type i` that starts from 0 can not possibly exceed maximum value representable by `vector::size_type` before exceeding the value returned by `vector::size`. It is safe.

---

> because, being of an unsigned type, i could overflow.

If this is direct quote, then it is an error and has been fixed in the 2nd edition where `i` is `int`. In that case `i` might overflow.

---

For what it's worth, I do not find (2nd edition) the part where Bjarne claims one to be *safer* than the other.

He claims that iterators do not have the range limitation that the indices have. And that is true. Iterators could theoretically support infinitely large ranges.

Using `size_type` to loop container elements has no problem of overflowing, but The fact that container interface supports `size_type` in the first place effectively causes the choice of `size_type` to limit the range of elements that a container can contain.

Comment: I quoted the exact text, however I have the first edition, maybe he corrected that bit in the following editions...